# align button right reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to align a button to the most right yet not sucessfull. Here is my attempt.

```html
<Button variant="contained" style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'right'}} color="primary" className="float-right" onClick={this.onSend}>
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: nop I am using material ui

Comment: For some reasons, I am restricted not to use bootstrap

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to add display flex to the parent element of your Button.

See sandbox here for example: https://codesandbox.io/s/testproviderconsumer-klcsr

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
        <button
          style={{ marginLeft: "auto" }}
        >
          Click
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`{{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}` are defined in the parent element to align items in the child element.

Comment: this works but I have two buttons that I would like to align to the left and this is causing on of them to be on top of the other

Comment: Is it possible to make both buttons on the same line

Comment: Can you post the mark-up for your buttons above? Will give me something to work-off of :)

Answer (score 8):

We can also use  float property to align.

```
<Button variant="contained" style={{float: 'right'}} color="primary" className="float-right" onClick={this.onSend}>
```

Answer (score 4):

**You have to defined in the parent element to align items in the child element.**

```
<div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}>
   <button>
          Click here
   </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<Button variant="contained" style={{ marginLeft: "auto" }} color="primary" onClick={this.onSend}>
Click
</Button>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit your answer to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).